# Add a class "active" on nav with php

Tags: php

I am building my own theme on wordpress, now i want my menu item to add a class "active"when it is active.

```
<div class="top-nav">
            <ul class="memenu skyblue">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <?php wp_list_pages( '&title_li=' ); ?>
```

In my functions.php i added this code.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current_page_parent', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
return $classes;
}
```

Now this code wouldnt add the class active to the li. Does anyone know what is wrong with the code??Or is there something i need to add to the code?

if i try this i get this output

```
 <ul class="memenu skyblue">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 current_page_item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: So, are you facing a issue in your code?

Comment: It isnt working,i will edit the question

Comment: There is obviously more to this code, if not then thats your problem, its incomplete. You declare the function special_nav_class but I dont see it executed anywhere.

Comment: how can i execute this the right way ?

Comment: Try my answer and update me if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `wp_list_pages()` function while you're filtering a `nav_menu_css_class` hook which is being **called only** by `Walker_Nav_Menu` and not by the function you use (wp_list_pages).

You can use the function with the `echo` parameter to return the HTML output instead of printing it. Then, look for that css class and act accordingly.

```
$list = wp_list_pages( 'echo=0' );
$list = str_replace('current_page_parent', 'current_page_parent active', $list);
echo $list;
```

**note:** usage of preg_replace and regular expressions would be a better idea.

**Update:**

The `active` class won't be added since none of the pages is the current page. According to the manual:

> The following classes are applied to menu items, i.e. to the HTML `<li>`
>   tags, generated by wp_list_pages(). Note: The wp_list_pages() and
>   wp_page_menu() functions output the same CSS classes.
>
> **.current_page_item** This class is added to menu items that correspond
>   to the currently rendered static page.
>
> **.current_page_parent** This class is added to menu items that correspond
>   to the hierarchical parent of the currently rendered static page.
>
> **.current_page_ancestor** This class is added to menu items that
>   correspond to a hierarchical ancestor of the currently rendered static
>   page.

NONE of them appear in the output so none of those pages is the current one and therefore the 'active' class won't be appended to any of them.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/

Comment: If i add your code ill get still my list with current pages. But the code will not add the class "active" to the list item.

Comment: Can you add the output of the code to your question?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: i have fixed the output now on the "active"page. do i now need to just style .current_page_item? (see edited question)

Comment: Exactly. If your goal was for CSS dedicated class, you've could simply add the WP defined class instead of trying to add a new class ("active").